# ¿Cómo subir imagenes utilizando editor quill.js?

Tags: javascript, quill

He estado practicando con quill.js para enviar textos de manera más dinámica. El problema es que al hacer un submit las imágenes se están enviando en formato base64 cuando yo simplemente quisiera guardar su `src = "nombre-imagen"`
Entonces lo que llevo hasta ahorita es esto:

```
var quill;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  // Inicializa Quill y asigna a la variable global quill
  quill = new Quill("#editor-container", {
    modules: {
      toolbar: [
        [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
        ["bold", "italic", "underline", { color: [] }],

        ["image"],
      ],
    },
    placeholder: "Ingresa tu mensaje...",
    theme: "snow", // or 'bubble'
  });

  
  var bsTooltip = document.querySelectorAll('[data-toggle="tooltip"]');
  bsTooltip.forEach(function (el) {
    new bootstrap.Tooltip(el);
  });
});
```

Si bien es cierto que funciona, tengo el inconveniente que en php recibo la imagen en formato base64 y no es lo que deseo. Ahora estuve probando hasta dar con esto:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    // Inicializa Quill y asigna a la variable global quill
    quill = new Quill("#editor-container", {
      modules: {
        toolbar: [
          [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
          ["bold", "italic", "underline"],
          ["image"],
        ],
      },
      placeholder: "Ingresa tu mensaje...",
      theme: "snow", // or 'bubble'
    });
  
    // Manejar imagenes
    quill.getModule("toolbar").addHandler("image", function () {
      // Abre el cuadro de diálogo de carga de imágenes
      const input = document.createElement("input");
      input.setAttribute("type", "file");
      input.setAttribute("accept", "image/*");
      input.addEventListener("change", function () {
        const file = input.files[0];
        if (file) {
       
          const fileName = file.name;
          // Inserta la imagen en el editor Quill
          const range = quill.getSelection();
          quill.insertEmbed(range.index, "image", fileName);
        }
      });
      input.click();
    });
  
  
    var bsTooltip = document.querySelectorAll('[data-toggle="tooltip"]');
    bsTooltip.forEach(function (el) {
      new bootstrap.Tooltip(el);
    });
  });
```

En cambio aquí sí logro hacer que la imagen se envíe como `<img src = "nombre-archivo"/>`
pero el problema es que en el editor la imagen no se está mostrando, entonces no sé qué más podría hacer. Llevo un buen rato sin encontrar solución. ¿Como podría lograr que se envíe la imagen en formato normal y no como base64, sin perder su previsualización en el editor?

Comment: Al final: ¿querés que se guarde _la imagen como tal_ o la _ruta_ de la imagen? Porque si es lo primero, lo que habría que hacer es decodificar base64 para visualizarla.

Comment: Gracias por responder mi idea era guardar todo el html que envia quill.js 
algo asi   <p>mi mensaje con imagen <img src="ruta-imagen"></p>
y obviamente almacenar la imagen en alguna carpeta para luego solo llamar la ruta. Entonces si en img iria la ruta.